# How to extend ToJson from persistent model

Tags: yesod

I'd like to *extend* the default `ToJson` instance of my model:

```
# models
Event
    title Text
    content Text
    deriving Eq
    deriving Show
```

How would I go about:

1. Adding the `id` to the ToJson
2. Can I somehow get the default one, and
   just extend it

I have tried to manually define my ToJson/FromJson but when I do:

```
getEventsR :: Handler Value
getEventsR = do
    events <- runDB $ selectList [] [ Desc EventId, LimitTo 5 ] :: Handler [Entity Event]

    return $ object ["data" .= events]
```

I get the following error:

```
Handler/Events.hs:10:29:
    No instance for (Foldable Entity) arising from a use of ‘.=’
    In the expression: "data" .= events
    In the first argument of ‘object’, namely ‘["data" .= events]’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘object ["data" .= events]’
```

Comment: How are you generating the current `ToJson` instance? You could get `To`/`FromJson` instances by adding `json` after your model name, [as described here](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#json-instances) (edit: to clarify, the Entity `ToJson` will have the ID added to the generated JSON)

Comment: @MaxGabriel Normally I would `Event json` so it would be auto-generated. Indeed, it includes the `id` only on listing not on `get404 eid`. 

Also, if I wanted to add for example other keys (e.g. `self: https://example.com/event/1`), how would I extend the auto-generated instances?

Comment: To answer my question, it seems we should write it manually -- https://pbrisbin.com/posts/writing_json_apis_with_yesod/